# Combining a collection of objects based on multiple properties

Tags: javascript, lodash

Is there a Javascipt or a Lodash method to combine this collection of objects:

```
[
{
  typeId: 'random1'
  catId: 'random2'
  val: '2'
},
{
  typeId: 'random1'
  catId: 'random2'
  val: '3'
},
{
  typeId: 'random1'
  catId: 'random4'
  val: '1'
}
]
```

into this one, with each object with unique typeId-catId pair and the numerical value to be summed up:

```
[
{
  typeId: 'random1'
  catId: 'random2'
  val: '5'
},
{
  typeId: 'random1'
  catId: 'random4'
  val: '1'
}
]
```

Comment: Well, you can likely use `_.mergeWith(object, sources, customizer)` but this doesn't sound like a very complicated function to write from scratch either. I doubt anything does that automatically, especially when those numbers are strings.

Comment: Looks a bit too specific to be handled out of the box by libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create an object which keeps track of total val of similar objects and then process them into final output format. Something like this:

```js
var data = [
{
  typeId: 'random1',
  catId: 'random2',
  val: '2'
},
{
  typeId: 'random1',
  catId: 'random2',
  val: '3'
},
{
  typeId: 'random1',
  catId: 'random4',
  val: '1'
}
];

var groups = data.reduce(function(acc, obj) {
  acc[obj.typeId+'_'+obj.catId] = acc[obj.typeId+'_'+obj.catId] || 0;
  acc[obj.typeId+'_'+obj.catId] += +obj.val;
  return acc;
}, {});


var result = Object.keys(groups).map(function(key) {
  return {
    typeId: key.split('_')[0],
    catId: key.split('_')[1],
    val : groups[key]
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `forEach()` loop and `thisArg` param to group objects by `typeId` and `catId` properties.

```js
var arr = [{"typeId":"random1","catId":"random2","val":"2"},{"typeId":"random1","catId":"random2","val":"3"},{"typeId":"random1","catId":"random4","val":"1"}]

var result = [];
arr.forEach(function(e) {
  var key = e.typeId + '|' + e.catId
  if(!this[key]) this[key] = e, result.push(this[key])
  else this[key].val = +this[key].val + +e.val
}, {});

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [query-js(*)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-js) for this. The module hasn't been maintained for a while though. You would do somthing like this:

```
arr.groupBy(function(e){return e.typeId + e.catId;}).each(function(grp){
  let first = grp.first();
  return {
            typeId : first.typeId,
            catId : first.catId,
            val : grp.sum(function(e){return 0 + e.val;})
          };
});
```

It will first group the objects and then do the calculation on each group

(*) Be aware that I'm entirely biased and you can't take my words as a recommendation but only suggestion, since I'm the creator of query-js

Answer (score 0):

What about this one ?

```
for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
  for (var j=i+1; j<array.length; j++) {
    if (array[i].typeId == array[j].typeId && array[i].catId == array[j].catId) {
      array[i].val = parseInt(array[i].val) + parseInt(array[j].val);
      array.splice(j--, 1);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Aren't you assuming that the array is sorted (on typeId first and the catId) and if that's not true you'd end up with multiple objects with the same combination of typeId and catId

Comment: Can you explain in more detail, or give me an example.

Comment: try with this array `var array = [
{
  typeId: 'random1',
  catId: 'random2',
  val: '2'
},
{
  typeId: 'random2',
  catId: 'random2',
  val: '3'
},
{
  typeId: 'random1',
  catId: 'random2',
  val: '1'
}
];` Instead of two objects it will be three (The first and last items have the same ids)